# NodeJs+React multer settings err

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

> NodeJS + Multer

Hi guys im trying to upload an image to my backend in Node from a React frontend but im constantly getting this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/avatar/avatar-Captura de pantalla de 2018-07-18 11-16-36_-1532639921615.png'
```

This is how i initialize multer in my back end

```
// Initialize multer storage
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "./public/avatar");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(
      null,
      file.fieldname +
        "-" +
        file.originalname.replace(path.extname(file.originalname), "_") +
        "-" +
        Date.now() +
        path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

and I receive with this

```
router.post(
  "/",
  upload.single("avatar"),
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
     //Code
   })
```

This is my Axios Post request from my react client

PS: ProfileData and avatar are payloads that I bring here throug redux (I dont think this should matter)

```
const image = new FormData();
  image.append("avatar", avatar, avatar.name);
  axios
    .post("/api/profile", image, profileData)
```

Comment: Not sure but probably it is because of the spaces in the file name.

Comment: Its the same error that way
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/avatar/avatar-branchlogo-1532643027870.png'

Comment: It look likes if it was looking for the file instead of creating it

Comment: Do you have `public/avatar` directory? Multer does not create directories if they don't exist.

Comment: Then, let me give an answer for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multer does not create directories if they don't exist. So, if not, just create the upload directory which is `public/avatar` in your case.

Comment: I have a little problem, when i receive the data in the express router it is possible to receive an object with user data and the multer image? how should i do that because the way i try its not working

Comment: Just ask another question about that with all your related code. Right now it is ambiguous what is what :) Like, where is user data, how you pass it to backend, etc. I'm not so expert but with a new question more people see your problem.